# Why is TypeScript not functioning as expected in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

i get errors in vscode but every thing works correctly .
some errors :

`Type expected.`

```
[{
    "resource": "/C:/Users/Dell/Desktop/vite-project/src/App.tsx",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "1110",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Type expected.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 10,
    "startColumn": 6,
    "endLineNumber": 10,
    "endColumn": 7
}]
```

`Cannot find name 'div'.`
`'>' expected.` ...

[image: somthing wrong in vscode settings]

[image: everything works]

Comment: Have you added the react type definition to your project?

Comment: @jagmitg how to do it ? (this is my first time with react)

Comment: `npm install @types/react @types/react-dom`

Comment: @jagmitg The problem is not in the code itself; the issue lies either in the TypeScript configuration or in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by updating the "jsx" setting in my tsconfig.json file. Initially, it was set to "jsx": "react", but changing it to "jsx": "preserve" solved the problem for me.
Here's the updated snippet from my `tsconfig.json`:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "jsx": "preserve"
  }
}
```

Additionally, I updated the TypeScript version to use the workspace version.